# Sails.js sockets, broadcast to one socket

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

When a user opens my website I subscribe them to their room, for example "room_USERNAME". So if a user has many tabs open all are subscribed to this room. So when another user sends a private message, I broadcast it to this room and all open tabs get the message.

However, I want to implement notification sounds. Since all tabs get the message, it will trigger notification sound on all tabs, which is "not cool". Is there a way to broadcast to only one of the sockets subscribed to "room_USERNAME" (broadcast messages to all sockets in a room but broadcast notification sound trigger to only one socket)?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most ideal way, but a temporary fix you could do is use the throttle underscore function http://underscorejs.org/#throttle